# Handling fscanf()

Tags: c, arrays, string, data-structures, scanf

I have a file which structure is simple:
`{number}\#

{some_text_with_lines}

\#`

The problem is that I want a program to read every entry in this file. This means this structure appears more than once.

So, my first thought was to create a struct array, some sort of `struct my_struct abc[MAX];`. `MAX` is a pre-processor definition.

I wanted the `fscanf` to store the {number} as the number of the array and the {some_text_with_lines} as a string inside the struct array. So each array would have it's own string.

The idea is fscanf read the following format: `%d#\r\n%s\r\n#r\n`, and use the first integer **%d** as the number of the array. Something like &abc[%d].
Although I know its syntax is wrong, I don't know how to read this number %d and use it as the number of the array. Also, there is a problem with the %s, it doens't have an \0?

So, I need some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish using `&abc[%d]`?

Comment: What you've asked include invalid code snippet. Try to express it clearly.

Comment: Do it in steps. 1. get the number, 2. get the string. Or, get the number and the string at the same time, storing the string in an intermediate buffer, then copy the string into the struct array. If it is even possible to do it in one go, the headache isn't worth it.

Comment: Will it store %s a \0 null terminator? My program keeps crashing when hadling any %s.

Comment: Is the number enclosed in braces? Is it followed by a backslash and a hash?  Is the file opened as a text file or as a binary file?  Is the end marker a line containing a backslash and a hash, or just a hash?  You seem to be expecting `\r\n` line endings, which suggests a Windows platform with a text file opened in binary mode. Why don't you show some example actual data?  How many lines can there be in 'some text with lines'?

Comment: The number is followed by a #. The file is a text file, with Windows endings.

Comment: If you open the file as a text file, then the line ending should appear as just `\n` in the program, even if the ending on disk is `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works.  It will accept an arbitrary list of paragraphs in the file, and the set of lines in each paragraph is allowed to be of arbitrary length, too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data
{
    int     number;
    char  **lines;
    int     num_lines;
    int     max_lines;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct data *info = 0;
    int   num_entries = 0;
    int   max_entries = 0;
    char line[4096];

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        int number;
        char hash;
        if (sscanf(line, "%d%c", &number, &hash) != 2 || hash != '#')
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Format error (number# expected): %s", line);
            return(1);
        }

        if (max_entries >= num_entries)
        {
            int new_size = (max_entries + 2) * 2;
            struct data *new_info = realloc(info, new_size * sizeof(*new_info));
            if (new_info == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
                return(1);
            }
            info = new_info;
            max_entries = new_size;
        }

        struct data *curr = &info[num_entries];
        curr->number    = number;
        curr->lines     = 0;
        curr->max_lines = 0;
        curr->num_lines = 0;

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
        {
            char *p = strchr(line, '\n');
            if (p == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Format error: no newline? (%s)\n", line);
                return(1);
            }
            *p = '\0';
            if (strcmp(line, "#") == 0)
                break;
            if (curr->max_lines >= curr->num_lines)
            {
                int new_size = (curr->max_lines + 2) * 2;
                char **new_lines = realloc(curr->lines, new_size * sizeof(*new_lines));
                if (new_lines == 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
                    return(1);
                }
                curr->lines = new_lines;
                curr->max_lines = new_size;
            }
            curr->lines[curr->num_lines] = strdup(line);
            if (curr->lines[curr->num_lines] == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
                return(1);
            }
            curr->num_lines++;
        }

        num_entries++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_entries; i++)
    {
        printf("%d#\n", info[i].number);
        for (int j = 0; j < info[i].num_lines; j++)
            printf("  %d: %s\n", j, info[i].lines[j]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Given the input file:

```
13#
Unlucky for some
#
20121221#
The end of the world?
No, it seems that we survived yet another doomsday!
#
18#
More lines,
And more lines still.
The verse is weird.
The terse is worse.
#
19#
As for one,
Then another,
It is still too short
For comfort,
But the fifth line shall trigger
an extra reallocation.
#
20#
All for one,
And one for all!
The Three Musketeers?
Nay, D'Artagnan, the Four Musketeers.
Yahoo! Bing?  Google?
#
```

It gives the output:

```
13#
  0: Unlucky for some
20121221#
  0: The end of the world?
  1: No, it seems that we survived yet another doomsday!
18#
  0: More lines,
  1: And more lines still.
  2: The verse is weird.
  3: The terse is worse.
19#
  0: As for one,
  1: Then another,
  2: It is still too short
  3: For comfort,
  4: But the fifth line shall trigger
  5: an extra reallocation.
20#
  0: All for one,
  1: And one for all!
  2: The Three Musketeers?
  3: Nay, D'Artagnan, the Four Musketeers.
  4: Yahoo! Bing?  Google?
```

There is undoubtedly room for improvement in the code, but it seems to work (though it does not release the memory before it exits).  It assumes that there is a function `char *strdup(const char *str)` that allocates enough space for a copy of the string it is given.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
int index;
char array[1024][1024];               // big array :)

while(fscanf(file, "%d#\r\n", &index) == 1) {
  fscanf(file, "%s\r\n", array[index]);
  int c; 
  while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && c != '\r') { }
  fgetc(file);                          // read '\n'
}
```

Comment: to skip over the last `\#` line

Comment: I see. I tried this option but I realized we have to deal with another problem: lines.  Although we can read the file, we have to read the other lines, and I'm struggling to get around this.

Comment: This code only reads the first appearance of the pattern. I have to read all the appeances of the pattern.

Comment: The checks on the I/O are all improper.  The outer loop will go on indefinitely on reaching EOF; the inner loop likewise.  The first condition should be `while (fscanf(file, "%d#\r\n", &index) == 1)` and the second should be `int c; while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF && c != '\r')`.  There is an argument that you should check the other two input operations too.